# CUDA cuSolver gesvdj with large matrix

Tags: cuda, cusolver

I am running a slightly modified version of the code found [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusolver/index.html) under section "G.2. SVD with singular vectors (via Jacobi method)" on a NVIDIA P6000. The slight modifications are to dynamically allocate memory in the heap for the A, U, and V vectors and to fill the A vector of a specified size with values that depend on the index into A. I also converted everything from doubles to floats. The last modification is a loop over the gesvdj call itself and convergence checking up to some # of iterations (10 in my case).

With those slight modifications, I was able to overcome my first hurdle of performing an SVD on symmetric arrays bigger than ~1000x1000 in size. I eventually need to run an SVD on a array of size 1048576x20.

Currently, the algorithm runs for arrays of size 10000x20 but fails when I go to 50000x20.

The issue seems to be stemming from the gesvdj call itself. A synchronize call after calling gesvdj is failing and returning a generic access error.

If I run the program using cuda-memcheck I get a series of these errors for different threads in the same block:

```
Invalid __global__ write of size 4
=========     at 0x00000108 in void eye_kernel<float, int=5, int=3>(int, int, float*, int)
=========     by thread (0,7,0) in block (16,1342,0)
=========     Address 0x7f4ed40414c0 is out of bounds
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at kernel launch time
=========     Host Frame:/lib64/libcuda.so.1 (cuLaunchKernel + 0x2c5) [0x269e85]
=========     Host Frame:/usr/local/cuda-10.0/lib64/libcusolver.so.10.0 [0x100c822]
=========     Host Frame:/usr/local/cuda-10.0/lib64/libcusolver.so.10.0 [0x100ca17]
=========     Host Frame:/usr/local/cuda-10.0/lib64/libcusolver.so.10.0 [0x1040dd5]
=========     Host Frame:/usr/local/cuda-10.0/lib64/libcusolver.so.10.0 [0x235c5d]
=========     Host Frame:/usr/local/cuda-10.0/lib64/libcusolver.so.10.0 (cusolverDnSgesvdj + 0x508) [0x21f9a8]
=========     Host Frame:./gesvdj_example [0x4518]
=========     Host Frame:/lib64/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main + 0xf5) [0x223d5]
=========     Host Frame:./gesvdj_example [0x3ab9]
```

I'm wondering if I have hit some sort of cusolver internal limitation? Anyone have any ideas? I can provide my exact code if necessary, but its so similar to the example that I figured I would just point people there.

Thanks!

Edit to add the offending code from the example I linked to, the algorithm is failing at the assert(CUSOLVER_STATUS_SUCCESS == status); line. I'm really new to coding in C and CUDA so sorry if there is some obvious debugging information I am leaving out.

```
/* step 5: compute SVD */
    status = cusolverDnDgesvdj(
        cusolverH,
        jobz,  /* CUSOLVER_EIG_MODE_NOVECTOR: compute singular values only */
               /* CUSOLVER_EIG_MODE_VECTOR: compute singular value and singular vectors */
        econ,  /* econ = 1 for economy size */
        m,     /* nubmer of rows of A, 0 <= m */
        n,     /* number of columns of A, 0 <= n  */
        d_A,   /* m-by-n */
        lda,   /* leading dimension of A */
        d_S,   /* min(m,n)  */
               /* the singular values in descending order */
        d_U,   /* m-by-m if econ = 0 */
               /* m-by-min(m,n) if econ = 1 */
        lda,   /* leading dimension of U, ldu >= max(1,m) */
        d_V,   /* n-by-n if econ = 0  */
               /* n-by-min(m,n) if econ = 1  */
        lda,   /* leading dimension of V, ldv >= max(1,n) */
        d_work,
        lwork,
        d_info,
        gesvdj_params);
    cudaStat1 = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    assert(CUSOLVER_STATUS_SUCCESS == status);
    assert(cudaSuccess == cudaStat1);
```

**Edit 2** Adding my code...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <cusolverDn.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<assert.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>
#include "cuda_runtime.h"

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{

    //Setting which device to run on
    const int device = 0;
    cudaSetDevice(device);

    cusolverDnHandle_t cusolverH = NULL;
    cudaStream_t stream = NULL;
    gesvdjInfo_t gesvdj_params = NULL;

    cusolverStatus_t status = CUSOLVER_STATUS_SUCCESS;
    cudaError_t cudaStat1 = cudaSuccess;
    cudaError_t cudaStat2 = cudaSuccess;
    cudaError_t cudaStat3 = cudaSuccess;
    cudaError_t cudaStat4 = cudaSuccess;
    cudaError_t cudaStat5 = cudaSuccess;
    const long int m = 50000;
    const long int n = 20;
    const int lda = m;

    // --- Setting the host, Nrows x Ncols matrix
    float *A = (float *)malloc(m * n * sizeof(float));
      for(long int j = 0; j < m; j++)
          for(long int i = 0; i < n; i++)
              A[j + i*m] = sqrt((float)(i + j));

    float *U = (float *)malloc(m * m * sizeof(float)); /* m-by-m unitary matrix, left singular vectors  */
    float *V = (float *)malloc(m * n * sizeof(float)); /* n-by-n unitary matrix, right singular vectors */
    float S[n];     /* numerical singular value */ 
    float *d_A = NULL;  /* device copy of A */
    float *d_S = NULL;  /* singular values */
    float *d_U = NULL;  /* left singular vectors */
    float *d_V = NULL;  /* right singular vectors */
    int *d_info = NULL;  /* error info */
    int lwork = 0;       /* size of workspace */
    float *d_work = NULL; /* devie workspace for gesvdj */
    int info = 0;        /* host copy of error info */

/* configuration of gesvdj  */
    const double tol = 1.e-7;
    const int max_sweeps = 100;
    const cusolverEigMode_t jobz = CUSOLVER_EIG_MODE_VECTOR; // compute eigenvectors.
    const int econ = 0 ; /* econ = 1 for economy size */

/* numerical results of gesvdj  */
    double residual = 0;
    int executed_sweeps = 0;

    printf("tol = %E, default value is machine zero \n", tol);
    printf("max. sweeps = %d, default value is 100\n", max_sweeps);
    printf("econ = %d \n", econ);
    printf("=====\n");

/* step 1: create cusolver handle, bind a stream */
    status = cusolverDnCreate(&cusolverH);
    assert(CUSOLVER_STATUS_SUCCESS == status);

    cudaStat1 = cudaStreamCreateWithFlags(&stream, cudaStreamNonBlocking);
    assert(cudaSuccess == cudaStat1);

    status = cusolverDnSetStream(cusolverH, stream);
    assert(CUSOLVER_STATUS_SUCCESS == status);

/* step 2: configuration of gesvdj */
    status = cusolverDnCreateGesvdjInfo(&gesvdj_params);
    assert(CUSOLVER_STATUS_SUCCESS == status);

/* default value of tolerance is machine zero */
    status = cusolverDnXgesvdjSetTolerance(
        gesvdj_params,
        tol);
    assert(CUSOLVER_STATUS_SUCCESS == status);

/* default value of max. sweeps is 100 */
    status = cusolverDnXgesvdjSetMaxSweeps(
        gesvdj_params,
        max_sweeps);
    assert(CUSOLVER_STATUS_SUCCESS == status);

/* step 3: copy A to device */
    cudaStat1 = cudaMalloc ((void**)&d_A   , sizeof(float)*lda*n);
    cudaStat2 = cudaMalloc ((void**)&d_S   , sizeof(float)*n);
    cudaStat3 = cudaMalloc ((void**)&d_U   , sizeof(float)*lda*m);
    cudaStat4 = cudaMalloc ((void**)&d_V   , sizeof(float)*lda*n);
    cudaStat5 = cudaMalloc ((void**)&d_info, sizeof(int));
    assert(cudaSuccess == cudaStat1);
    assert(cudaSuccess == cudaStat2);
    assert(cudaSuccess == cudaStat3);
    assert(cudaSuccess == cudaStat4);
    assert(cudaSuccess == cudaStat5);

    cudaStat1 = cudaMemcpy(d_A, A, sizeof(float)*lda*n, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    assert(cudaSuccess == cudaStat1);
    /* step 4: query workspace of SVD */
    status = cusolverDnSgesvdj_bufferSize(
        cusolverH,
        jobz, /* CUSOLVER_EIG_MODE_NOVECTOR: compute singular values only */
              /* CUSOLVER_EIG_MODE_VECTOR: compute singular value and singular vectors */
        econ, /* econ = 1 for economy size */
        m,    /* nubmer of rows of A, 0 <= m */
        n,    /* number of columns of A, 0 <= n  */
        d_A,  /* m-by-n */
        lda,  /* leading dimension of A */
        d_S,  /* min(m,n) */
              /* the singular values in descending order */
        d_U,  /* m-by-m if econ = 0 */
              /* m-by-min(m,n) if econ = 1 */
        lda,  /* leading dimension of U, ldu >= max(1,m) */
        d_V,  /* n-by-n if econ = 0  */
              /* n-by-min(m,n) if econ = 1  */
        lda,  /* leading dimension of V, ldv >= max(1,n) */
        &lwork,
        gesvdj_params);
    assert(CUSOLVER_STATUS_SUCCESS == status);

    cudaStat1 = cudaMalloc((void**)&d_work , sizeof(float)*lwork);
    assert(cudaSuccess == cudaStat1);

/* step 5: compute SVD */
    //Iterating over SVD calculation, not part of example
    int iters;
    for (iters = 10; iters > 0; iters--){

    status = cusolverDnSgesvdj(
        cusolverH,
        jobz,  /* CUSOLVER_EIG_MODE_NOVECTOR: compute singular values only */
               /* CUSOLVER_EIG_MODE_VECTOR: compute singular value and singular vectors */
        econ,  /* econ = 1 for economy size */
        m,     /* nubmer of rows of A, 0 <= m */
        n,     /* number of columns of A, 0 <= n  */
        d_A,   /* m-by-n */
        lda,   /* leading dimension of A */
        d_S,   /* min(m,n)  */
               /* the singular values in descending order */
        d_U,   /* m-by-m if econ = 0 */
               /* m-by-min(m,n) if econ = 1 */
        lda,   /* leading dimension of U, ldu >= max(1,m) */
        d_V,   /* n-by-n if econ = 0  */
               /* n-by-min(m,n) if econ = 1  */
        lda,   /* leading dimension of V, ldv >= max(1,n) */
        d_work,
        lwork,
        d_info,
        gesvdj_params);

    cudaStat1 = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    assert(CUSOLVER_STATUS_SUCCESS == status);
    assert(cudaSuccess == cudaStat1);

    cudaStat1 = cudaMemcpy(U, d_U, sizeof(float)*lda*m, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaStat2 = cudaMemcpy(V, d_V, sizeof(float)*lda*n, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaStat3 = cudaMemcpy(S, d_S, sizeof(float)*n    , cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaStat4 = cudaMemcpy(&info, d_info, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaStat5 = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    assert(cudaSuccess == cudaStat1);
    assert(cudaSuccess == cudaStat2);
    assert(cudaSuccess == cudaStat3);
    assert(cudaSuccess == cudaStat4);
    assert(cudaSuccess == cudaStat5);

    if ( 0 == info ){
        printf("gesvdj converges \n");
    }else if ( 0 > info ){
        printf("%d-th parameter is wrong \n", -info);
        exit(1);
    }else{
        printf("WARNING: info = %d : gesvdj does not converge \n", info );
    }
    }
/* step 6: measure error of singular value */
    status = cusolverDnXgesvdjGetSweeps(
        cusolverH,
        gesvdj_params,
        &executed_sweeps);
    assert(CUSOLVER_STATUS_SUCCESS == status);

    status = cusolverDnXgesvdjGetResidual(
        cusolverH,
        gesvdj_params,
        &residual);
    assert(CUSOLVER_STATUS_SUCCESS == status);

    printf("residual |A - U*S*V**H|_F = %E \n", residual );
    printf("number of executed sweeps = %d \n\n", executed_sweeps );

/*  free resources  */
    if (A      ) free(A);
    if (V      ) free(V);
    if (U      ) free(U);
    if (d_A    ) cudaFree(d_A);
    if (d_S    ) cudaFree(d_S);
    if (d_U    ) cudaFree(d_U);
    if (d_V    ) cudaFree(d_V);
    if (d_info ) cudaFree(d_info);
    if (d_work ) cudaFree(d_work);

    if (cusolverH    ) cusolverDnDestroy(cusolverH);
    if (stream       ) cudaStreamDestroy(stream);
    if (gesvdj_params) cusolverDnDestroyGesvdjInfo(gesvdj_params);

    cudaDeviceReset();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you  sure this isn't something simple like running out of memory? Because you have provided literally no details, only you are going to be able to diagnose and solve this....

Comment: Like I said in the post, I am really new to C and CUDA. What information can I provide to help in diagnosing the issue? The debugging information I could find I posted. I am getting an memory access error and when I check with cuda-memcheck I get ~20 of those error messages I posted. How do I check if I am using too much memory?

Comment: The code you posted helps. When I run your code with cuda-memcheck, I get `Program hit cudaErrorMemoryAllocation (error 2) due to "out of memory" on CUDA API call to cudaMalloc.` (on a device with about 4Gb of free memory). Like I said, you are probably running out of memory. A pen an paper calculation should tell you for sure, given you know how much memory your GPU has

Comment: Hmm its a Quadro P6000 which I think has 24GB of memory. I'm only allocating 4 arrays * 4 bytes * (50000 * 20 entries) = 0.016 GB right? I'm able to do this SVD calculation in Python with ease even given all the overhead from Python. These arrays really aren't that big.

Edit: I guess the work space could be rather large that is being assigned to the operation, but I would think that would fail in its own right during the following status check.

Comment: I see at least one allocation of lda x m which is going to be 4 x 50000 x 50000 bytes , which is 10Gb by my reckoning

Comment: Oof, you're right. I don't understand why I didn't get such an explicit error from cuda-memcheck, the result I got was pretty cryptic in comparison. 

Ok well, thank you for putting up with my "dross" and living up to your profile and handing me a downvote :)

I think the solution is to turn econ = 1 and reduce the size of the arrays, hopefully that fixes the issue.

Comment: I am going to guess that you actually didn't run out of memory, but rather didn't have enough allocated because you have `lwork` defined as a signed 32 bit integer, which would be limited to 2G words (and you would need 2.5G words), so that is why the kernel fails with out of bounds memory access. Like I said the devil here is in details (i.e. code) which you didn't provide. I ran out of memory because I have a 4Gb card so the initial cudaMalloc calls produced out of memory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you to @talonmies for the help in diagnosing the problem. cusolver's gesvdj method has an economy mode which stores the U and V matrices in more economical arrays. The modifications I made to make the code work are simple.

```
econ = 1
U array size (mxn)
V array size (nxn)
ldv paramater = n
```

Code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <cusolverDn.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<assert.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>
#include "cuda_runtime.h"

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{

    //Setting which device to run on
    const int device = 0;
    cudaSetDevice(device);

    cusolverDnHandle_t cusolverH = NULL;
    cudaStream_t stream = NULL;
    gesvdjInfo_t gesvdj_params = NULL;

    cusolverStatus_t status = CUSOLVER_STATUS_SUCCESS;
    cudaError_t cudaStat1 = cudaSuccess;
    cudaError_t cudaStat2 = cudaSuccess;
    cudaError_t cudaStat3 = cudaSuccess;
    cudaError_t cudaStat4 = cudaSuccess;
    cudaError_t cudaStat5 = cudaSuccess;
    const long int m = 1048576;
    const long int n = 20;
    const int lda = m;

    // --- Setting the host, Nrows x Ncols matrix
    float *A = (float *)malloc(m * n * sizeof(float));
      for(long int j = 0; j < m; j++)
          for(long int i = 0; i < n; i++)
              A[j + i*m] = sqrt((float)(i + j));

    float *U = (float *)malloc(m * n * sizeof(float)); /* m-by-m unitary matrix, left singular vectors  */
    float *V = (float *)malloc(n * n * sizeof(float)); /* n-by-n unitary matrix, right singular vectors */
    float S[n];     /* numerical singular value */ 
    float *d_A = NULL;  /* device copy of A */
    float *d_S = NULL;  /* singular values */
    float *d_U = NULL;  /* left singular vectors */
    float *d_V = NULL;  /* right singular vectors */
    int *d_info = NULL;  /* error info */
    int lwork = 0;       /* size of workspace */
    float *d_work = NULL; /* devie workspace for gesvdj */
    int info = 0;        /* host copy of error info */

/* configuration of gesvdj  */
    const double tol = 1.e-7;
    const int max_sweeps = 100;
    const cusolverEigMode_t jobz = CUSOLVER_EIG_MODE_VECTOR; // compute eigenvectors.
    const int econ = 1 ; /* econ = 1 for economy size */

/* numerical results of gesvdj  */
    double residual = 0;
    int executed_sweeps = 0;

    printf("tol = %E, default value is machine zero \n", tol);
    printf("max. sweeps = %d, default value is 100\n", max_sweeps);
    printf("econ = %d \n", econ);
    printf("=====\n");

/* step 1: create cusolver handle, bind a stream */
    status = cusolverDnCreate(&cusolverH);
    assert(CUSOLVER_STATUS_SUCCESS == status);

    cudaStat1 = cudaStreamCreateWithFlags(&stream, cudaStreamNonBlocking);
    assert(cudaSuccess == cudaStat1);

    status = cusolverDnSetStream(cusolverH, stream);
    assert(CUSOLVER_STATUS_SUCCESS == status);

/* step 2: configuration of gesvdj */
    status = cusolverDnCreateGesvdjInfo(&gesvdj_params);
    assert(CUSOLVER_STATUS_SUCCESS == status);

/* default value of tolerance is machine zero */
    status = cusolverDnXgesvdjSetTolerance(
        gesvdj_params,
        tol);
    assert(CUSOLVER_STATUS_SUCCESS == status);

/* default value of max. sweeps is 100 */
    status = cusolverDnXgesvdjSetMaxSweeps(
        gesvdj_params,
        max_sweeps);
    assert(CUSOLVER_STATUS_SUCCESS == status);

/* step 3: copy A to device */
    cudaStat1 = cudaMalloc ((void**)&d_A   , sizeof(float)*lda*n);
    cudaStat2 = cudaMalloc ((void**)&d_S   , sizeof(float)*n);
    cudaStat3 = cudaMalloc ((void**)&d_U   , sizeof(float)*lda*n);
    cudaStat4 = cudaMalloc ((void**)&d_V   , sizeof(float)*n*n);
    cudaStat5 = cudaMalloc ((void**)&d_info, sizeof(int));
    assert(cudaSuccess == cudaStat1);
    assert(cudaSuccess == cudaStat2);
    assert(cudaSuccess == cudaStat3);
    assert(cudaSuccess == cudaStat4);
    assert(cudaSuccess == cudaStat5);

    cudaStat1 = cudaMemcpy(d_A, A, sizeof(float)*lda*n, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    assert(cudaSuccess == cudaStat1);
    /* step 4: query workspace of SVD */
    status = cusolverDnSgesvdj_bufferSize(
        cusolverH,
        jobz, /* CUSOLVER_EIG_MODE_NOVECTOR: compute singular values only */
              /* CUSOLVER_EIG_MODE_VECTOR: compute singular value and singular vectors */
        econ, /* econ = 1 for economy size */
        m,    /* nubmer of rows of A, 0 <= m */
        n,    /* number of columns of A, 0 <= n  */
        d_A,  /* m-by-n */
        lda,  /* leading dimension of A */
        d_S,  /* min(m,n) */
              /* the singular values in descending order */
        d_U,  /* m-by-m if econ = 0 */
              /* m-by-min(m,n) if econ = 1 */
        lda,  /* leading dimension of U, ldu >= max(1,m) */
        d_V,  /* n-by-n if econ = 0  */
              /* n-by-min(m,n) if econ = 1  */
        n,  /* leading dimension of V, ldv >= max(1,n) */
        &lwork,
        gesvdj_params);
    assert(CUSOLVER_STATUS_SUCCESS == status);

    cudaStat1 = cudaMalloc((void**)&d_work , sizeof(float)*lwork);
    assert(cudaSuccess == cudaStat1);

/* step 5: compute SVD */
    //Iterating over SVD calculation, not part of example
    int iters;
    for (iters = 10; iters > 0; iters--){ 
    status = cusolverDnSgesvdj(
        cusolverH,
        jobz,  /* CUSOLVER_EIG_MODE_NOVECTOR: compute singular values only */
               /* CUSOLVER_EIG_MODE_VECTOR: compute singular value and singular vectors */
        econ,  /* econ = 1 for economy size */
        m,     /* nubmer of rows of A, 0 <= m */
        n,     /* number of columns of A, 0 <= n  */
        d_A,   /* m-by-n */
        lda,   /* leading dimension of A */
        d_S,   /* min(m,n)  */
               /* the singular values in descending order */
        d_U,   /* m-by-m if econ = 0 */
               /* m-by-min(m,n) if econ = 1 */
        lda,   /* leading dimension of U, ldu >= max(1,m) */
        d_V,   /* n-by-n if econ = 0  */
               /* n-by-min(m,n) if econ = 1  */
        n,   /* leading dimension of V, ldv >= max(1,n) */
        d_work,
        lwork,
        d_info,
        gesvdj_params);

    cudaStat1 = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    assert(CUSOLVER_STATUS_SUCCESS == status);
    assert(cudaSuccess == cudaStat1);

    cudaStat1 = cudaMemcpy(U, d_U, sizeof(float)*lda*n, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaStat2 = cudaMemcpy(V, d_V, sizeof(float)*n*n, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaStat3 = cudaMemcpy(S, d_S, sizeof(float)*n    , cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaStat4 = cudaMemcpy(&info, d_info, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaStat5 = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    assert(cudaSuccess == cudaStat1);
    assert(cudaSuccess == cudaStat2);
    assert(cudaSuccess == cudaStat3);
    assert(cudaSuccess == cudaStat4);
    assert(cudaSuccess == cudaStat5);

    if ( 0 == info ){
        printf("gesvdj converges \n");
    }else if ( 0 > info ){
        printf("%d-th parameter is wrong \n", -info);
        exit(1);
    }else{
        printf("WARNING: info = %d : gesvdj does not converge \n", info );
    }
    }
/* step 6: measure error of singular value */
    status = cusolverDnXgesvdjGetSweeps(
        cusolverH,
        gesvdj_params,
        &executed_sweeps);
    assert(CUSOLVER_STATUS_SUCCESS == status);

    status = cusolverDnXgesvdjGetResidual(
        cusolverH,
        gesvdj_params,
        &residual);
    assert(CUSOLVER_STATUS_SUCCESS == status);

    printf("residual |A - U*S*V**H|_F = %E \n", residual );
    printf("number of executed sweeps = %d \n\n", executed_sweeps );

/*  free resources  */
    if (A      ) free(A);
    if (V      ) free(V);
    if (U      ) free(U);
    if (d_A    ) cudaFree(d_A);
    if (d_S    ) cudaFree(d_S);
    if (d_U    ) cudaFree(d_U);
    if (d_V    ) cudaFree(d_V);
    if (d_info ) cudaFree(d_info);
    if (d_work ) cudaFree(d_work);

    if (cusolverH    ) cusolverDnDestroy(cusolverH);
    if (stream       ) cudaStreamDestroy(stream);
    if (gesvdj_params) cusolverDnDestroyGesvdjInfo(gesvdj_params);

    cudaDeviceReset();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please remember to come back and accept this in a few days so the question falls off the unanswered queue for the CUDA tag